# How to represent distances between two coordinates

Tags: cartodb

I have a simple DataSet with 2 different coordinates by record.

[image]

*(dem_latitude & dem_longitude are one coordinate, html_latitude & html_longitude are the other coordinate)*

My main purpose is to **see** how big are the distances between each couple of coordinates.

As an clarification I don't want to see the distance as a number but represented in the map with the 2 coordinates (that form a couple) easily recognisable.

Solutions I can image but I don't know how to develop:

1. I can see for each coordinate which is its partner, maybe through a line.
2. Events like clicking in one coordinate makes the partner coordinate to be highlighted.

Any suggestion of how to implement any of this solutions or any other suggestion to achieve my "main purpose"?

If the solution is using the WYSIWYG CartoDB editor better :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inspired by the @blat's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33168665/316700), and after dealing with a lot of weird errors with *SRIDs codes* and *the_geom_webmercator* vs *the_geom*, I got this solution:

```
select
  st_transform(
    st_makeline(
      st_setsrid(st_makepoint(html_longitude,html_latitude), 4326),
      st_setsrid(st_makepoint(dem_longitude,dem_latitude), 4326)
    ),
    3857 
  ) as the_geom_webmercator
from the_data_set
```

If you also want to show the initial and the end point you have to create **extra layers** for each coordinate couple and then do something like:

```
select
  cartodb_id,
  st_transform(
    st_setsrid(st_makepoint(dem_longitude,dem_latitude), 4326),
    3857 
  ) as the_geom_webmercator
from the_data_set
```

The result looks like this:

[image]

Comment: If you are curious about the result check [this map](https://daliaresearch.cartodb.com/viz/e1c0027a-741c-11e5-b533-0e3ff518bd15/embed_map), but I'm not sure if it is gonna be active for long.

Answer (score 2):

CartoDB UI and CartoDB WYSIWYG are very good and intuitive but when working with a single geometry per row. I'm not an expert, but I think in this case you'll need to use your developer super-powers and:

1 - alter the table schema and add a new column distance

2 - run a simple query to update that column value based on the points information:

```
UPDATE <table_name> SET distance = (SELECT ST_Distance(
    ST_GeographyFromText(
      'SRID=4326;POINT(' || dem_longitude || ' ' || dem_latitude || ')'
    ),
    ST_GeographyFromText(
      'SRID=4326;POINT(' || html_longitude || ' ' || html_latitude || ')'
    )
  )
);
```

Remember you can run queries using the API, so it's easy to integrate this query in any callback that adds data to the table to keep it updated.

Comment: Very interesting and it helps me for another things, in this case, though, I'm looking for a graphical representation of the distance, not the distance as  number, I would like to see the 2 dots and connected by a line or something. I have added a clarification to the question _"As an clarification I don't want to see the distance as a number but represented in the map with the 2 coordinates (that form a couple) easily recognisable."_, also I have changed the dataset screenshot to show that I don't need to calculate the distance.